# Apache + PHP not showing any formating

Tags: php, debian, apache2

What I am going to ask is probably a simple problem but I can't figure out solution. I have installed apache2 on Debian server and updated php to version 7.3. I think that I have made a mistake when disabling/enabling some modules but I am not sure.

Since that moment, text formatting/styles are not shown at all. [See the image please, it is a result of pure phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZBJS.png)

What do I do?

Error log shows nothing

> [Tue May 25 23:33:51.759710 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27142] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
> [Tue May 25 23:33:51.759811 2021] [core:notice] [pid 27142] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

apache2.conf

```
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


HostnameLookups Off


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/apache2/stapling_cache(128000)
<VirtualHost *:443>


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
Header always set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()"
ServerName CENSORED
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSORED/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSORED/privkey.pem
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
SSLUseStapling on
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Modules:
    Loaded Modules:
     core_module (static)
     so_module (static)
     watchdog_module (static)
     http_module (static)
     log_config_module (static)
     logio_module (static)
     version_module (static)
     unixd_module (static)
     access_compat_module (shared)
     alias_module (shared)
     auth_basic_module (shared)
     authn_core_module (shared)
     authn_file_module (shared)
     authz_core_module (shared)
     authz_host_module (shared)
     authz_user_module (shared)
     autoindex_module (shared)
     deflate_module (shared)
     dir_module (shared)
     env_module (shared)
     filter_module (shared)
     headers_module (shared)
     mime_module (shared)
     mpm_prefork_module (shared)
     negotiation_module (shared)
     php7_module (shared)
     proxy_module (shared)
     proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
     proxy_http_module (shared)
     reqtimeout_module (shared)
     rewrite_module (shared)
     setenvif_module (shared)
     slotmem_shm_module (shared)
     socache_shmcb_module (shared)
     ssl_module (shared)
     status_module (shared)
```

If it comes to the modules there might be actually some mistakes; i tried to install php7.3 fpm bud ended up using the "not fpm" version.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hi Maty, and welcome to ServerFault. Please share your *complete* apache2 config (apart from Debian's defaults of course) to give us any chance of helping you.

Comment: I have added some configs of Apache. What others would you like to see? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I resolved the problem. The only thing I had to do was removing the CSP header from SSL apache config file. Since then it works normally.
TIP for everyone: Check developers console